# How to get all substrings in single quotes or double quotes in JS?

Tags: javascript

There is the following string:

```
import lodash from 'lodash';
window._ = lodash;

import angular from "angular";
window.angular = angular;
```

I want to get all libraries which are used in this page, therefore I want to get all names from single quotes or double quotes. How can I do it using JS? I thought to use 'match' function but I couldn't finish it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can to Regex your own code or string?

Comment: `.match(/(['"]).*?\1/g)` perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean as some form of pre-processor when building your JavaScript? do you mean at run time? If the former look into some linting tools. If its for warnings.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - it's right, but may this regexp avoid quotes in result?

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this? You are essentially trying to parse JS, which should be necessary only in very special cases, and if it is, then you should use a JS parser, not regexp. To take a simple example, what if your code contains a comment with a quoted string inside?

Comment: @malcoauri Unfortunately that would require the use of a lookbehind to find the opening quote (regex would be `/(?<(['"])).*?(?=\1)/`), and JavaScript does not support lookbehinds. You will need to just strip off the first and last characters - `substr(1,-1)` should do the trick.

Comment: It's some specific task for webpack, not matter

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - torazabuto was right, we need to parse string after 'from' word and 'require' word. How can I do it? Thanks